# javascript dropdown navigation menus missing in RTM

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

in the beta's of Visual Studio 2013 there used to be dropdown menus at the top of the javascript editor which worked similarly to that in c# and vb editing.

Were these pulled from the RTM or final release or is it available with a certain version or setting change.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [was removed from the RTM](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805871/there-is-no-navigation-bar-in-text-editor-for-javascript-files) for reliability reasons.